# Can't sign in with Yahoo Messenger?

Tags: yahoo-messenger

I'm using the latest version of Yahoo msgr but it won't let me sign in and says "possible problem with secure HTTP connection". BTW my internet connection is fine. I used a vpn before but not now.

I have verified that my system's clock is set correctly. I have reinstalled Yahoo Messenger and rebooted my PC and the problem persists.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

Your question seems to have been thoroughly answered [here](http://www.fixya.com/support/t4093388-try_connect_yahoo_messenger_get):

> Internet Explorer is used to sign into Yahoo Messenger. If you have another browser set as default, IE will still sit as a link between your browser and Yahoo Messenger. For this reason most troubleshooting is concentrated on Internet Explorer.
>
> 1. Upgrade IE and update any support software (Flashplayer, Java, Shockwaveplayer)
> 2. On the sign in page, click 'Messenger' > Connection Preference. Toggle between 'Connect direct to the internet' and 'Proxy setting' to make sure the information is correct in the lower 2 boxes.
>
>    Check these settings in IE (even if you have another browser set as default):
>
>    - Tools > Internet options > Connections > Lan settings > check 'Automatically detect settings - uncheck other options.
>    - Tools > work offline - make sure this is NOT checked and has a red X through it
> 3. Disable your firewall and test to see if you can sign in.
> 4. Control Panel > Internet Options > Connections > LAN Settings > Uncheck Proxy server,  check automatically detect settings.
> 5. Control Panel > Internet Options > Connections > dial-up and virtual private Network setting > select your default connection > setting > check automatically detect setting
> 6. If you are unable to sign into this secure page: https://login.yahoo.com/config/login?.src=fptx._intl=uk. Copy the yahoo https address above and paste it in:
>
>    IE > tools > internet options > LAN settings - check automatically detect settings > Advanced - paste in 'Secure' window > OK